# getting mouse event to work consistently in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, events, mouse

I am working on a simple program to create circle nodes when a "factory" icon is clicked, then delete the nodes when they are clicked. My question is why the d3 selectAll statement (above the createNode function) does not work when I run the script after page load, though it all runs fine when I cut and paste that same statement into the browser console. I suspect it's because I am not chaining method calls correctly, but would appreciate some advice. Thank you.

```js
    var w=5000,h=400,ctr=0; //define bounds of svg

        var ND=[]; //holder of all node data

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg') //base svg element
          .attr('width',w)
          .attr('height',h);

    function random(p,q) { return p+Math.floor(Math.random()*(q-p)); }

    var factory=svg.append('circle') //draw the factory widget
        .attr('class','perms') //one of the perm objects
        .attr('cx',50)
        .attr('cy',50)
        .attr('r',30)
        .attr('stroke','black')
        .attr('fill','teal');

    factory.on('click',createNode); //create a new node when factory is clicked

        d3.selectAll('.nodes').on('click',function(e,d){ var did=this.id; console.log(did); 
                            d3.select(this).transition().delay(1000).style('fill','orange').remove();});

    function createNode(x,y) //create a new node and render on screen
    { var r=30; var lx=random(100+r,w-r); var ly=random(0+r,h-r); 
      var rx=svg.append('circle').attr('class','nodes').attr('id',ctr)
        .attr('cx',lx).attr('cy',ly).attr('r',r)
        .attr('stroke','red').attr('fill','yellow');
      var rn={id:ctr++, x:lx, y:ly, r:30, clr:'yellow',lnk:[],ptr:0};
      ND.push(rn);
      return rn;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I also tried the below, but again, it only executes the createNode branch. The other branch only works if I paste the full function body into the console. I have a hunch this might be because I am not using enter, update, and exit correctly, but don't know enough in d3 to fix it. Have read a few tutorials and SO examples but still stuck. Appreciate the help.

```
d3.selectAll('circle').on('click',function(d)
        { k=d3.select(this); console.log(k.classed('perms')); console.log(k.attr('class')); 
          if (k.classed('perms')) { createNode();}
          if (k.classed('nodes')) { did=this.id; console.log(did);
             for(var i=0;i<ND.length;i++){if (ND[i].id==did){ND.splice(i--,1);}}
             d3.select(this).transition().delay(1000).style('fill','orange').remove();
            }});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is why the d3 selectAll statement (above the createNode function) does not work when I run the script after page load, though it all runs fine when I cut and paste that same statement into the browser console.

Currently you append a factory node that creates new nodes on click.

Then you select all *existing* circles with class node. At this point there are none.

Then you can click on the factory node, create a new one, but you don't re-run the selectAll statement. The selection of all circles is not updated because a new circle is created afterwards.

What you could do is run the selectAll statement again after you append a node, but you only add one node at a time, and you already have a selection of that node in the `createNode` function. So you can just add the event listener here:

```
 function createNode(x,y) { 
    var r=30; var lx=random(100+r,w-r); var ly=random(0+r,h-r); 
    var rx=svg.append('circle')
      .attr('class','nodes')
      ...
      .on(...

     ...
}
```

```js
    var w=500,h=400,ctr=0; //define bounds of svg

        var ND=[]; //holder of all node data

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg') //base svg element
          .attr('width',w)
          .attr('height',h);

    function random(p,q) { return p+Math.floor(Math.random()*(q-p)); }

    var factory=svg.append('circle') //draw the factory widget
        .attr('class','perms') //one of the perm objects
        .attr('cx',50)
        .attr('cy',50)
        .attr('r',30)
        .attr('stroke','black')
        .attr('fill','teal');

    factory.on('click',createNode); //create a new node when factory is clicked


    function createNode(x,y) //create a new node and render on screen
    { var r=30; var lx=random(100+r,w-r); var ly=random(0+r,h-r); 
      var rx=svg.append('circle').attr('class','nodes').attr('id',ctr)
        .attr('cx',lx).attr('cy',ly).attr('r',r)
        .attr('stroke','red').attr('fill','yellow')
        .on('click',function(e,d){ var did=this.id; console.log(did); 
                            d3.select(this).transition().delay(1000).style('fill','orange').remove();});
                            
      var rn={id:ctr++, x:lx, y:ly, r:30, clr:'yellow',lnk:[],ptr:0};
      ND.push(rn);
      return rn;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

The selectAll code works in the console after you add circles because now there are circles to select - otherwise you have an empty selection. One way you can check to see if you are indeed selecting anything is to use `selection.size()` to return how many elements are selected.